# How to use +[SBLockScreenManager sharedInstance] in iOS tool (jailbroken)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos

I'm developing a simple tool that request for device to unlock from a command line. However, using these code below, nothing seems to happen (the `sharedInstance` code are verified to be correct using Cycript, and device did receive the unlock request)

```
#include <stdio.h>

@interface SBLockScreenManager : NSObject
+ (id)sharedInstance;
- (void)tapToWakeControllerDidRecognizeWakeGesture:(id)arg1;
- (void)lockScreenViewControllerRequestsUnlock;
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
    [[NSClassFromString(@"SBLockScreenManager") sharedInstance] lockScreenViewControllerRequestsUnlock];
    return 0;
}
```

How do I achieve this properly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That won't work, as `SBLockScreenManager` is part of the `Springboard` app.

It's not a framework you can link against.

You will only be able to access that class whilst inside of the `Springboard` app - hence via a tweak.

**You can try**:

1) Developing a simple `Springboard` tweak (b.i. `com.apple.springboard`) that listens for a system-wide notification, and once that notification is received, trigger the unlock request.

See [CFNotificationCenterPostNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542592-cfnotificationcenterpostnotifica?language=objc) and [CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542572-cfnotificationcentergetdarwinnot) for further details.

2) Just send the notification from your command line utility